# Using Linq to Entities to poulate comboBoxes in a winforms application, one comboBox dependent on the other

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, linq-to-entities

Here is my code;

```
        comboBoxAdminVisit.DataSource = be.Events;
        comboBoxAdminVisit.DisplayMember = "EventName";


        var fff = (from cc in be.Visitors
                  select cc.Attending).FirstOrDefault();

        var ggg = (from xx in be.Events
                   where xx.Id == fff
                   select xx.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (fff == ggg)
        {
            foreach (var name in comboBoxAdminName.Items)
            {
                comboBoxAdminName.Items.Add(name);
            }
```

cc.Attending is a foreign key, it stores the priomary key of the event tabel. I want to select an event from the first combo box and have the second populated with those attending the event. Thanks in advance!

```
Events       Visitors
------       --------
Id           Id
Attendee(FK) Name
EventName    Company
EventStart   Car Reg
EventEnd     Visiting
```

Comment: Can you attach your Data Diagram? It will help establish some relations between entites

Comment: I think you have many-to-many relation between Event and Visitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exact structure of your entities, but here is an idea how to implement it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxAdminVisit.DataSource = be.Events;
    comboBoxAdminVisit.DisplayMember = "EventName";
}

private void comboBoxAdminVisit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBoxAdminVisit.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Event selectedEvent = (Event)comboBoxAdminVisit.SelectedItem;

        var visitors = (from cc in be.Visitors
                        where cc.Attending.Events.Contains(x => x.EnventId = selectedEvent.Id)
                        select cc);

        comboBoxAdminName.DataSource = visitors;
        comboBoxAdminName.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's put me on the right track. It's not working with the data model yet, but I'll change things around and when it's done I'll mark as answer, probably tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, just had to change the linq a little and it worked. I've edited your answer to include the correct linq.